# Unity ошибка CS0246

Tags: c#, unity3d

добавил код для рекламы и вот такая проблема :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class InterstitialAds : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsLoadListener, IUnityAdsShowListener
{

    [SerializeField] private string androidAdID = "Interstitial_Android";
    [SerializeField] private string iOSAdID = "Interstitial_iOS";

    private string adID;

    void Awake()
    {
        adID = (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
            ? iOSAdID
            : androidAdID;
        LoadAd();
    }

    public void LoadAd()
    {
        Debug.Log("Loading Ad: " + adID);
        Advertisement.Load(adID, this);
    }

    public void ShowAd()
    {
        Debug.Log("Showing Ad: " + adID);
        Advertisement.Show(adID, this);
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsShowFailure(string placementId, UnityAdsShowError error, string message)
    {
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsShowStart(string placementId)
    {
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsShowClick(string placementId)
    {
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsShowComplete(string placementId, UnityAdsShowCompletionState showCompletionState)
    {
        LoadAd();
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsAdLoaded(string placementId)
    {
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsFailedToLoad(string placementId, UnityAdsLoadError error, string message)
    {
    }
}
```

вот второй :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class AdsInitializer : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsInitializationListener
{

    [SerializeField] string androidGameID = "4488585";
    [SerializeField] string iOSGameID = "4488584";
    [SerializeField] bool testMode = true;
    private string gameID;

    void Awake()
    {
        InitializeAds();
    }
    public void InitializeAds()
    {
        gameID = (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer) ? iOSGameID : androidGameID;
        Advertisement.Initialize(gameID, testMode, this);
    }

    public void OnInitializationComplete()
    {
        Debug.Log("Unity Ads initialization complete.");
    }

    public void OnInitializationFailed(UnityAdsInitializationError error, string message)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Unity Ads Initialization Failed: {error.ToString()} - {message}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Совсем нет идей, что значит текст этой ошибки? Вбейте в переводчик. Где код брали, там должно быть сказано, какие модули надо подключить к проекту.

Comment: Хорошо может если с этим не получается то тогда может подскажете для другого способа  что делать если я скачал плагин для адмоб и после этого игра на телефоне не запускается вылазит ошибка приложение останавливается ?